# Global error handling in ASP.NET web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, webforms

I want to handle errors globally in my web forms application. and want to redirect on an error page after exception occurred.

I did following changes in web config.

```
 <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error/Index">
    <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Error/YourPage"/>             
  </customErrors>
```

It is working fine if don't have `try` `catch` block in my page.
But my application is already live and it has lot of `try` `catch` blocks without `throw` error.

If I `throw` error from `catch` than `customErrors` is working fine.

But in all `catch` blocks there is no `throw` keyword and I don't want to change all the `catch` blocks.

I also tried `Application_Error` method in `global.asax` but same thing is happening there also.

So is it possible that I can redirect on custom error without changing all `catch` blocks?

Comment: As far I know no... these error handlers are for unhandled exception, if you catch them you're handing them, the only alternatives that I get will require even more efforts for reach your objective than change all catch blocs.

Answer (score 0):

I think, remove try / catch block or throw exception in catch block. Because catch block without throw exception ignore global exception handling.

I would remove try / catch block, throw exception by status and use Application_Error event.